# AngularJS - controller method doesn't get called on ngClick - no error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to call the method `removePlayer(playerId)` if a button gets clicked. But, the method doesn't get called, or at least the statements inside it aren't firing, because I put a `console.log()` statement at the top.

The console is empty, so I'm really clueless. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
function appController($scope) {
    $scope.players = [];
    var playercount = 0;

    $scope.addPlayer = function(playername) {

        $scope.players.push({name: playername, score: 0, id: playercount});
        playercount++;
    }

    function getIndexOfPlayerWithId(playerId) {
        for (var i = $scope.players.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            if ($scope.players[i].id == playerId)
                return i;
        }
    }

    $scope.removePlayer = function(playerId) {
        console.log("remove");
        var index = getIndexOfPlayerWithId(playerId);
        $scope.players.slice(index, 1);
    }
}
appController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

HTML:

```
...
<table id="players">
        <tr ng-repeat="player in players">
            <td>{{player.name}}</td>
            <td>{{player.score}}</td>
            <td><button ng-click="removePlayer({{player.id}})">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
...
```

Comment: Why is the player object in the controller, not in the model?

Comment: I was just trying out AngularJS, just to discover what it was. It wasn't a 'real' project. @LeeGee

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You shouldn't be using curly braces (`{{ }}`) in the ng-click expression. You should write:

`<button ng-click="removePlayer(player.id)">Remove</button>`

Comment: Does the new ng-repeat scope just inherit from the parent scope? So the `$parent` in my answer wouldn't be necessary?

Comment: Yes, scopes created by `ng-repeat` inherit from a parent scope so the `$parent` reference is not needed. In fact one should rather avoid using `$parent` since it strongly links expressions in the event handlers with the template structure (it is enough to insert another scope-creating directive and things might break).

Comment: Thanks, that all makes sense. I just remember seeing places that were using `$parent` in an `ng-repeat`, and was thinking this was the issue. +1 to you.

Answer (score 4):

`ng-repeat` creates a new scope, so it doesn't know what `removePlayer` is. You should be able to do something like this:

```
<table id="players">
    <tr ng-repeat="player in players">
        <td>{{player.name}}</td>
        <td>{{player.score}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="$parent.removePlayer({{player.id}})">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/NXyZHRTAnLA

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about this. Trying now!

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle that recreates the problem? That'll make it easier to diagnose the exact problem. Also, I just noticed the `{{}}` in the call to the function. I believe you don't need those when calling the function.

Answer (score -1):

As stated, ng-repeat creates it's own scope, and the outer controller scope is not available. But since in JS you are using true objects write something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in players">
    <td>{{player.name}}</td>
    <td>{{player.score}}</td>
    <td><button ng-click="player.removePlayer()">Remove</button></td>
</tr>
```

Beforehand, somewhere on your controller initialization you can assing the "removePlayer" function to each of your player object and naturally code in anything you want, thus accessing outer controller indirectly.